# Does Gatsby need to rebuild my entire site every time a docpage is updated?

Tags: javascript, contentful, gatsby

I am creating a Documentation site to hold DocPages for each of my products. Gatsby is building all of my sites as static pages. I have multiple tech writers who are constantly updating and creating new pages. How does Gatsby handle this? Do I have to rebuild my entire site with Gatsby each time something is updated?

Answer (score 1):

`gatsby-source-contentful` plugin uses the [sync](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/concepts/sync/) API. If you keep the `.cache` and `public` folder around the plugin will be able to get only the changed entries and assets and update the Gatsby data. by keeping the `.cache` should build faster.

depend on you webhook Setup this build process may be triggered many times to workaround that maybe you can add a script that delays the builds and make sure that only one build process is running.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question, but I struggled with this today and it seems noone out there gave a decent post or answer about it, Gatsby v2 still rebuilds everything when you restart gatsby develop. This is a no-go if your build takes 20min on first run. My solution is below.

You could use the [cache API](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/build-caching/#the-cache-api)  to save a hash or updatedAt info of your data, and only call createPage action if the cache doesn't match (the data was updated)

This is how I do it in my project:

```
exports.createPages = async ({ actions: { createPage }, graphql, cache }) => {
  const results = await graphql(`
    query GetAllCars {
      myNamespaceFromGraphqlSource {
        allCars {
          id
          updatedAt
        }
      }
    }
  `);

  const createDetailsPage = async (car) => {
    const carCache = await cache.get(car.id);
    if(carCache != car.updatedAt) {
      createPage({
        path: `/car_details/${car.id}/`,
        component: require.resolve("./src/templates/details.js"),
        context: {
          id: car.id,
        },
      });
      await cache.set(car.id, car.updatedAt);
    }
  }

  for(let i=0; i < results.data.myNamespaceFromGraphqlSource.allCars.length; i++ ) {
    const car = results.data.myNamespaceFromGraphqlSource.allCars[i];
    await createDetailsPage(car)
  }
```